# wget "giving up" -- closed fd 3

Tags: wget, timeout

I apologize in advance for being dense but I can't figure out why wget is "giving up".  Here is the command I'm using.

`wget --debug --tries 1 --read-timeout=900 --timeout=0 http://secure.sample.com/site/test`

Here is a portion of the wget debug:

```
--2012-12-13 17:43:19--  http://secure.sample.com/site/test
Resolving secure.sample.com... 100.100.100.100
Caching secure.sample.com => 100.100.100.100
Connecting to secure.sample.com|100.100.100.100|:80... connected.
Created socket 3.
Releasing 0x0000000000e658e0 (new refcount 1).

---request begin---
GET /site/test HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Wget/1.12 (linux-gnu)
Accept: */*
Host: secure.sample.com
Connection: Keep-Alive

---request end---
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... No data received.
Closed fd 3
Giving up.
```

I tried echoing out some data as it looks like it's seeing no response and I also tried flushing the output buffers (in case the data was there just not sent).  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

ok, I've successfully reproduced your output, with a local URL:

```
% wget --debug --tries 1 --read-timeout=900 --timeout=0 http://localhost:5000/foo/bar
Setting --tries (tries) to 1
Setting --read-timeout (readtimeout) to 900
Setting --timeout (timeout) to 0
DEBUG output created by Wget 1.13.4 on darwin10.8.0.

URI encoding = `US-ASCII'
--2012-12-13 19:54:40--  http://localhost:5000/foo/bar
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1, ::1, fe80::1
Caching localhost => 127.0.0.1 ::1 fe80::1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:5000... connected.
Created socket 3.
Releasing 0x000000010041d0f0 (new refcount 1).

---request begin---
GET /foo/bar HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Wget/1.13.4 (darwin10.8.0)
Accept: */*
Host: localhost:5000
Connection: Keep-Alive

---request end---
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... No data received.
Closed fd 3
Giving up.
```

how did I do it ? Well, that's easy, on the other side, I opened a service on the port 5000, and closed it once the request has been transmitted:

```
% nc -kl 5000
GET /foo/bar HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Wget/1.14 (darwin10.8.0)
Accept: */*
Host: localhost:5000
Connection: Keep-Alive

GET /foo/bar HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Wget/1.13.4 (darwin10.8.0)
Accept: */*
Host: localhost:5000
Connection: Keep-Alive

^C
```

So, what all that means, is that the server you're trying to connect to is either not a `HTTP` server or is buggy. It opens a socket when you knock to the port, and once you've given your `HTTP` speech, it closes right away (or after a timeout, you did not tell). Anyway, `wget` is working just fine, your service is not.

If you think that's `wget`'s fault, did you try using `curl` instead ?

Comment: I assumed wget's timeout was an issue but I didn't consider apache/php was closing the connection because we have other long running calls.  I'm using ubuntu apache (2.2.22) with 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 and I am setting the timeout with PHP's set_time_limit(0);.  Any suggestions on what is closing the connection?